# Invalid write of size 8 valgrind even for NULL assignment

Tags: c, valgrind

I have a structure like this

```
struct chromosome
{
    float fitness;                                          /** Fitness of the chromosome. i.e Value calucated by 
                                                                            fitness function */
    char *genes;                                            /** Genes of the chromosome */

    struct meta_chromosome *meta_chromosome;                /** Pointer to the  meta_chromosome structure */
};
```

I am trying to create one instance of structure like this

```
/*
 * Allocates memory fore the chromosome and related objects 
 */
struct chromosome *
create_chromosome(struct meta_chromosome *meta_chromosome)
{
    struct chromosome *chromosome = NULL;
    chromosome = malloc(sizeof(chromosome));


    chromosome->genes =  NULL;
    chromosome->genes = malloc((meta_chromosome->len + 1 ) * sizeof(char) );

    chromosome->meta_chromosome = meta_chromosome;

    return chromosome;
}
```

But when I am compile it and run valgrind I get this error

```
Invalid write of size 8
==3584==    at 0x400856: create_chromosome (chromosome.c:54)
==3584==    by 0x4008A5: gen_random_chromosome (chromosome.c:68)
==3584==    by 0x400FA0: init_rand_population (genetic_algorithm.c:177)
==3584==    by 0x40115E: main (main.c:47)
==3584==  Address 0x52021a8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==3584==    at 0x4C2BBCF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

What might be the problem

Comment: Don't name your instance variable the same as the name of your struct, this is masking the error where you're `malloc`ing the size of the pointer, not the size of the struct

Comment: There is no need to cast `NULL` to `char *` .

Comment: It would be nice if you told us what line 54 actually corresponds to.  You might want to read this in the future, as to reproduce your problem, we'd need to write our own program: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Setting a pointer to NULL immediately before assigning the result of `malloc()` to the same pointer is pointless.  Your compiler will almost certainly optimize it away, but you probably shouldn't write it.  You could use: `struct chromosome *chromosome = malloc(sizeof(*chromosome));` or equivalent, and then check that the assignment worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space:

```
chromosome = malloc(sizeof(chromosome));
```

`chromosome` is of type `struct chromosome *`, which according to valgrind is 8 bytes.  But the struct is of type `struct chromosome`, which is larger.

Allocate space for the struct, not a pointer to it:

```
chromosome = malloc(sizeof(*chromosome));
```

Or:

```
chromosome = malloc(sizeof(struct chromosome));
```

Comment: Ouch, I missed it in a blink of eye

Comment: @Goutam There are two types of programmers:  those that have made mistakes just like that, and liars.  ;-)